# Displaying facebook feed using FB.api

Tags: facebook, hashtag

I want a to display my facebook feed in my site that show only specific #hashtag, for example "#StarComm". This is my code.

```
    var page_id = 'MY APP ID';
var pageaccessToken='MY Token';
FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed?q=%23StarComm&access_token='+ pageaccessToken, {limit:5} , function(response){
       if (response && response.data && response.data.length){

        var ul = document.getElementById('pagefeed');
      for (var j=0; j<response.data.length; j++){
        var feed = response.data[j],
        li = document.createElement('li'),
         a = document.createElement('a');
        a.innerHTML = feed.message;
        a.href = feed.link;
        li.appendChild(a);
        ul.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
  });
```

My out put is like this.

```
Follow us on twitter at https://twitter.com/StarcommOnline #StarComm
```

And i want my output is like the standard fb:like-box. Thanks in Advance!